# Difference between words

Tags: difference

I am learning English and I do not know what the difference is between some words. There are some words whose meaning is the same, but the words are different. For example, *home* and *house*, or *car* and *automobile*, or *hi* and *hello*, or *female* and *woman*, and so on.

Could you please tell me the differences between these pairs?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, hassan. This is a very broad question. There are tens of thousands of such pairs, so the question cannot be answered. We call such questions Not Constructive. Questions about individual pairs can be answered; but it is best if you consult a dictionary first, like [this one](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/), and then come back here to ask about anything that leaves you confused. Finally, we ask that you use ordinary spelling here, with capitals and punctuation: it is much easier to read.

Comment: These are called "Synonyms". There are millions of synonyms in English language and for obvious reasons, no one can list them all for you here. You can try learning about the ones you see in your real life while reading, watching movies, etc. Please See this: [Synonyms](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synonyms)

Comment: For just about any word in English, you can look up a thesaurus to find the word's synonyms (words where the meaning is similar) or antonyms (words where the meaning is the opposite).  Good luck

Comment: please tell me different between these word that i called.i do not need more than this

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. Carlo_R has edited your question to correct spelling, and I have incorporated the substance of your Comment; in future you should do this yourself, by clicking the 'edit' link below the question. I fear, however, that the question will be closed; as I said, you really should consult a good dictionary and only bring us questions which  that cannot resolve.

Answer (score 6):

For the specific examples you give:

- Home - the principal place where someone lives
- House - any building designed for humans to live in

Car / Automobile basically mean the same thing but Car is typical UK English whereas Automobile is more common in the USA

Hi / Hello are both a greeting, Hi is less formal than Hello

- Female - can refer to an organism of any type (animal, human...) and
  typically means those members of the species who produce eggs
- Woman - a female, adult human

.

Answer (score 2):

home - a place where you and your family live

house - a building

car - a transport that can help you to move from the point A to the point B

authomobile - a transport too, but the context should provide any technical details

hi - informal, but can be used in business letters.

hello - formal

You can say "Hi" to your friend, but "Hello" to your chief or a chief of your chief:)